# How do I fix vim colors in OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, colors, zsh

I've been trying to fix this for weeks, to no avail, and it's been really frustrating.

Here is the issue:

[image]

Fed up with the wrong colors and general plugin mess, I decided to wipe my `.vim` and `.vimrc`
However, the problem still persists.

- My default Terminal theme is Monokai, but I've tested several others.
- I tried numerous 256-color terminal themes, including the default.
- I use `zsh` installed via `brew` with OhMyZsh primarily, but I've tried running it in `bash` as well.
- I'm using `vim` 7.4.712 installed via `brew`, but I've tested my system default as well, which is `vim` 7.3
- I tried setting `set t_Co=256` in my `.vimrc` previously
- OS X Yosemite 10.10.4
- Apparently `echo $TERM` should output `xterm-256color`, however mine outputs `xterm-color`. And I did "declare terminal as `xterm-256color`" in my Terminal Preferences.

I did notice these lines in my `.zshrc` which seem to point at the problem but I have no idea how to fix this.

`if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
            export TERM='xterm-256color'
    else
            export TERM='xterm-color'
    fi`

From my investigation, `/usr/share/terminfo/x/` doesn't exist.
Instead, I found these folders in `/usr/share/terminfo/`:

```
31 33 35 37 39 45 4d 50 58 62 64 66 68 6a 6c 6e 70 72 74 76 78
32 34 36 38 41 4c 4e 51 61 63 65 67 69 6b 6d 6f 71 73 75 77 7a
```

`terminfo` doesn't exist under `/usr/local/share/` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your .zshrc is changing your terms colors. Just replace this:

```
if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
            export TERM='xterm-256color'
    else
            export TERM='xterm-color'
fi
```

with this:

```
export TERM='xterm-256color'
```

or remove it completely.

Comment: On the spot. Running export='xterm-256color' in Terminal fixes the issue...until I restart Terminal. I can't figure out what's setting it to 'xterm-color' on startup. I deleted those lines from .zshrc, added the export line like you suggested. I scoured all the bash/zsh/rc/profile files in ~, found and deleted 2 more instances of the same if else block, but it's still in some file somewhere. How can I pinpoint its source?

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to restart Terminal properly

Comment: Also, I was suggested elsewhere to use [[ $TERM = xterm* ]] && TERM='xterm-256color' instead, to avoid messing things up if I used screen or another terminal emulator